# Delete Link Button not working in GridView using ASP

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, gridview

So there's not much to explain, I have a GridView and I put a Delete button which asks if you're sure you want to delete when you click it. I'm using VisualStudio2012 and I've done this in many other pages but I've never gotten this problem.

GridView:

```
<asp:GridView ID="MaintenanceTable" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Maintenance_ID" DataSourceID="MaintDataSource" EmptyDataText="There are no data records to display." BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" GridLines="Vertical" Width="1000px">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#DCDCDC" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="DeleteButton" Text="Delete"
                    CommandName="delete"
                    OnClientClick="if (!window.confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item?')) return false;" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" ShowSelectButton="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Maintenance_ID" HeaderText="Maintenance_ID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Maintenance_ID" />
        <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="Status" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Date" SortExpression="Date" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Notes" HeaderText="Notes" SortExpression="Notes" />
    </Columns>
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" ForeColor="Black" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#34397D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#999999" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#EEEEEE" ForeColor="Black" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#008A8C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#0000A9" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#000065" />
</asp:GridView>
```

This really is the only code I've added in terms of deleting in my GridView:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="DeleteButton" Text="Delete"
                    CommandName="delete"
                    OnClientClick="if (!window.confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item?')) return false;" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the following code:

```
protected void MaintenanceTable_RowCommand(object sender, 
                     GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
  {
    // get the maintenanceId of the clicked row
    int maintenanceId = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
    // Delete the record 
    DeleteRecordByID(maintenanceId);
    // Implement
   }
}
```

Just incase, make sure you use "Delete" not "delete".

Check this resource [GridView Delete, with Confirmation](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12666/GridView-Delete-with-Confirmation)